# Overwriting in add object to arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, addition, overwrite

this thing right here is giving me some headache for a while, I'm trying to find the problem and can't find an answer. Basically, it's overwriting every single previous object in the list.

```
public class ProcessadorDeSinaisImpl implements ProcessadorDeSinais {

private List<GeradorDeEvento> gerador = new ArrayList<GeradorDeEvento>();

private List<Evento> listaEvento = new ArrayList<Evento>();


public void adicionarGerador(GeradorDeEvento geradorDeEvento) {
    gerador.add(geradorDeEvento);
}   

public List<Evento> processarSinais(List<Sinal> sinais) { // Lista de sinais gerada pelo GeradorDeSinais !!!!
    Evento resultado;
    for(int i=0; i < gerador.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j < sinais.size(); j++)
        {
            resultado = new EventoImpl();
            resultado = gerador.get(i).gerarEvento(sinais.get(j));

            if(resultado != null)
            {
                listaEvento.add(resultado); 
            }
        }
    }
    return listaEvento;
}
```

}

Comment: This line ` resultado = new EventoImpl();`is useless since resultado is assigned the reference to a different object right at the next  line. What is the problem exactly that you are having?

Comment: @alainlompo the problem I am having is that, even if I'm receiving Evento's that are not null from "gerador.get(i).gerarEvento(sinais.get(j)), they are overwriting each other as I add them to the list. This happens before the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
 Evento resultado = new EventoImpl();
 resultado = gerador.get(i).gerarEvento(sinais.get(j));
```

Having the variable declared outside the loop my be causing issues